# Sending required mail content using mail.jar and activation.jar

Tags: java, email, activation

Am using mail.jar and activation.jar as classpath and have programmed a automatic mail sending and it works fine.

In my program, the content is declared as a String. But my requirement is, I need to retrieve few of the counts from different tables of my SQL DB and attach the same in my content of the mail.

I think declaring the content as String will not help me out to achieve the task since the number of lines that I will be sending in the content of the mail will be more than five or six.

Kindly let me know how a large text can be added to the content of the mail. Any sort of links or tutorials for justifying the same will be highly appreciable. Thanks a lot in advance.. Happy Sunday guys.. !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably familiar with `System.out.println` etc... You can use this method to print to a string like this:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);

pw.println("Hello");            // Appends two
pw.println("World");            // separate lines

pw.printf("Hello %d World", 5); // Using printf

pw.println();                   // appends a new-line
pw.print("Another line.");      // appends string w/o new-line

pw.println();                   // appends two
pw.println();                   // newlines

String rowFormat = "%8s %8s %8s %8s %8s%n";
pw.printf(rowFormat, "Col A", "Col B", "Col C", "Col XY", "Col De", "Col Ef");
pw.printf(rowFormat, "A", "19", "Car", "55", "Blue", "Last");
pw.printf(rowFormat, "X", "21", "Train C", "-4", "Red", "Demo");
pw.printf(rowFormat, "B", "-9", "Bike", "0", "Green", "Column");

String message = sw.toString();

System.out.println(message);
```

The above snippet of code would (in the last `System.out.println`-call) print:

```
Hello
World
Hello 5 World
Another line.

   Col A    Col B    Col C   Col XY   Col De
       A       19      Car       55     Blue
       X       21  Train C       -4      Red
       B       -9     Bike        0    Green
```

This way you could easily construct an email message string using `println`-method calls.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think I could manage using this. And is it possible to form a table with three rows and six columns using a string in the content of the mail?

Comment: Yes. I would definitely go for `printf` if I would need to lay out a table

Comment: Any examples available in web for defining the same?

Comment: Thanks a lot.. You are making things look easier

Answer (score 1):

If you simply need to send a few lines instead of one, you can still use a single String. A String can hold multiple lines of text. Just add newlines where necessary.

Actually assuming your mail body is in plain text format, you should use CR LF as a line terminator (`\r\n` at the end of each line).

So you can build your content like this:

```
String content = "This is line 1 of the email\r\n"
    + "This is line 2 of the email\r\n"
    + "This is line 3 of the email\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [link text][1] for dynamically merging parameters with a String. Instead of a static String you could consider loading the text as a resource from the classpath.

[1]: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...)